# How to find memory leaks in c++ code invoked from a python script (with boost::python)

Tags: python, c++, memory, boost, shared-libraries

What is the best way to find memory leaks in c++ code invoked from a python script (with boost::python library).

For example, say this is my c++ code:

```
#include <boost/python.hpp>

class Test {

public:

    Test() {}

};

BOOST_PYTHON_MODULE(Test) {
  bpl::class_<Test>("Test", bpl::init<>());
}
```

The c++ code above is packed in a shared object named "test.so", used by this python script:

```
import test;

t = test.Test();
```

My question: how can I find memory leaks in my c++ code?

Comment: Strip away all the code required to call from python. Compile and run the stripped code, find and fix the memory leak in that. Once you have done that, make sure when calling from python, that the the clean up operation in C++ code is also executed before python exits.

Comment: Thanks @stackoverblown! That was my first thought, but I was wondering whether there is some python tool or library (maybe boost::python itself) that provides memory leaks detection. As for your suggestion: if I strip all the code required to call from pthon, I should then write a c++ program that invokes my c++ library's functionality in order to look for memory leaks (say, with valgrind), right?

Comment: Something like that. On second thought, maybe you could just leave the python code there. I would imagine they would not interfere much if you are using the class Test purely within C++.